# Sudo with scp - transfering local file to remote server using ssh

Tags: windows, sudo, scp

So I'm running the following command

```
scp \desktop\myfolder\deployments\myfile.txt user@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

In an attempt to transfer a file from my local windows 7 machine to a remote server (using putty).  This works with the exception that I don't have write permissions to that folder.

So if I do the following...
1) log into server using putty
2) sudo su - myadminuser
3) run scp, how would I use the myadminuser?  If I try something like...

```
scp \desktop\myfolder\deployments\myfile.txt **myadminuser**@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

The problem is I don't have the myadminuser login.

Comment: I have answered on [another posting](http://superuser.com/a/1120455/559952) how you can customize scp do the sudo for you directly. This is similar to what WinSCP does.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:
you can't do that directly.

Extended answer:
Use SCP to transfer the file to a directory where you have write access with that user, then use ssh to move the file with sudo
e.g.: ssh host sudo mv myfile.txt /path/to/the/destination

Comment: // , Did it work?

Comment: In most cases I think you'd have to add the -t option for this to work. See http://askubuntu.com/a/281743